# Georgia font does not render correctly on Windows

Tags: css, fonts

Using Georgia for body copy on a web site we've noticed major differences between how the text is rendered on a mac vs Windows.

It would appear the issue is with Windows when using smaller font sizes, since the text rendered by the browser (tested in Chrome, Safari, Firefox) looks very different to the installed font.

At 36px the text rendered by the browser (top) matches the text typed directly into PhotoShop (bottom):

[image: Georgia at 36px]

At 12px the text rendered by the browser is very different (characters look elongated):

[image: Georgia at 12px]

Can anyone explain why this is the case? We need to ensure consistent rendering of type across browsers/platforms.

#### Update

It's worth noting that if I import the system font directly (using @font-face), the type renders correctly.

Comment: Well for one thing, neither Photoshop nor most browsers use the system font renderer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure consistent rendering use an image, there is simply no consistent font rendering across systems. The font renderer for Windows is is very different from the font rendering in Mac OSX. Here is an elaborate article on the topic: [Link](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html)

Comment: I just can't up vote while "use an image" is part of this answer.

Comment: If you say so, please enlight me and tell me another way for consistent font rendering across systems. I personally don't care for this topic. So the font looks different on a Mac than a Windows machine. If I start wondering about this little differences I quit my job.

Comment: Ben noted in his question that the face renders correctly when including it via \@font-face Using an image for text has Usability and SEO impacts that are more important than pixel perfect fonts, IMO.

Comment: Andrew, I totally agree. I couldn't care less about pixel perfect rendering. I just stated the case that in my opinion it's not possible without an image, because the differences in font rendering are too high.

Answer (score 0):

"It's worth noting that if I import the system font directly (using @font-face), the type renders correctly."

Why don't you simply import the system font directly, then?

On the other hand, I'm with Florian. The difference is minor enough I wouldn't really be concerned with it.

Comment: I disagree, the difference between Windows and MAC is very noticeable.  I am importing the font directly but I want to understand *why* this is happening.

Comment: I found this article, it might be a bit more helpful than I've been: http://www.rfwilmut.clara.net/about/fonts.html